# CATextLayer : Text is not showed

Tags: ios, objective-c, catextlayer

When I tried to add image as CATextLayer content, text is not shown. Only image is shown. This is my code which I have placed in `viewDidLoad()` method,

```
    UIImage *uiimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flying.png"];
    CATextLayer *textLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    textLayer.frame = CGRectMake(144, 42, 76, 21);
    textLayer.font = CFBridgingRetain([UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18].fontName);
    textLayer.fontSize = 18;
    textLayer.foregroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
    textLayer.string = @"Hello world";
    textLayer.contents = (id)uiimage.CGImage;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
```

Please help to solve the issue.

Comment: Why not just creat two layers, one for the image and one for the text?

Comment: That works. But wanted to know if setting the content of the text layer works.

Comment: Hardly think so, I think setting the string is a convinience way of setting the contents of CATextLayer, so if you set the contents again, the text will be overridden. However it is just my guess, havn't verified.

Comment: I am agree with Eric Qian's answer,  and if you real want to show the `image` and the `text` I suggest you add the text to the `img` by `photoshop`